# Ask user for source directory and destination; make a new directory

Tags: java, file, directory, mkdir

This is one step of a programming assignment I have been having some trouble with over the past few weeks. I am rewriting my code to try to get it to work.

The first step I am working on is to: Make a new directory with the same name as the source directory but in the new destination.

As you can see by my code, I ask the user for the name of the source directory and for the destination the user wants this directory to be copied to. Eventually, I will copy the entire directory (including subdirectories and files) to a new directory in the new location which the user inputted.

Here is my code. I attempted to copy something from my flash drive to my desktop but it did not work.

```
package recursivedirduplication;

/**
 * @author zhughes3
 * Last edited Tuesday, March 31st, 2014 @ 12pm
*/

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RecursiveDirDuplication {

/**
 * The following program:
 * 1. Asks the user for the source directory and destination.
 * 2. Makes a new directory in the new location with the same name
 *    as the source directory.
 * 3. Creates an array with File class objects for each item in the contents
 *    of the source directory.
 * 4. Next, it iterates the array, and for each item in the array:
 *    - if it is a file, it copies the file to the new directory using the 
 *      copyFile() method taken from CopyFileDemoE.
 *    - if it is a directory, recursively call this method to copy the 
 *      directory and all of its contents.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    // Create a new instance of Scanner to get user input
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

    //Ask user to input the directory to be copied
    System.out.print("Input directory to be copied.");

    //Save input as a String
    String source = scanner.nextLine();

    //Ask user to input destination where directory will be copied
    System.out.print("Input destination where directory will be moved to.");

    //Save input as String
    String dest = scanner.nextLine();

    //Make a new directory in the new location with the same name as the
    //source directory
    createDir(source,dest);
}

public static void createDir (String source, String dest) throws Exception{

    //Create a File object for new directory in new location with same name
    //as source directory
    File newDir = new File (dest + source);

    //Create a new directory in new user-inputted destination with same name
    //as the source directory
    newDir.mkdir();
}
```

As you can tell by the steps in the notes regarding the program: I am only trying to handle step 2 at this point.

I get very confused when it comes to creating new File objects because I don't understand how the syntax works because of the file paths and names. Its very difficult for me to comprehend it. Is my code wrong? Is there any instruction/tips anyone can give me regarding this.

The goal is to ask the user for the source directory and the new destination that he wants the directory to be copied to. Now my goal is to simply create a new directory in the new destination with the same name as the source destination.

Taking this one step at a time to understand it completely.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys.

------------------------------------------EDIT #1:-----------------------------------------
After looking around at other Stackoverflow Problems I changed the code in my second method createDir to this:

```
public static void createDir (String source, String dest) throws Exception{

    //Create a File object for new directory in new location with same name
    //as source directory
    File newDest = new File (dest);

    File newDir = new File (newDest, source);

    //Create a new directory in new user-inputted destination with same name
    //as the source directory
    newDir.mkdirs();
    }
```

With this, I was able to write a file from the flash drive to my desktop. 
This is what my program outputted:

```
Input directory to be copied./Volumes/DJ BLU-Z/Letters to Palmer
Input destination where directory will be moved to./Users/Zhughes3/Desktop
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 22 seconds)
```

It added the directory Volumes to my desktop. However, I want it to send the directory "Letters to Palmer" to my desktop.

Any advice people?

--------------------------------EDIT #2 w/ Correct Answer----------------------------------
Here is the changes I made to the second method of my program which allowed me to write the user-inputted directory to the new destination.

```
public static void createDir (String source, String dest) throws Exception{

    //Create File objects for the source directory and new destination
    File sourceFile = new File (source);
    File newDest = new File (dest);

    //Create new File object using the File object of the new destination 
    //and the last name in the pathname's name sequence of the source Dir
    File newDir = new File (newDest, sourceFile.getName());

    //Create a new directory in new user-inputted destination with same name
    //as the source directory
    newDir.mkdir();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is convert source and dest into files (`new File(String)`) and then use `new File(File,String)` to create your final folder location (remember, for String you only need name so use `destFile.getName()`

Comment: Can you please give me a coded example. I took what you said as to do this: 'File newSource = new File (source);
        
        File newDest = new File (dest);'

Comment: Although this could have been explained better, your advice helped me come to the correct answer. I edited my question to include the answer.